# Node ORM2 Test Hangs

Tags: node.js, orm, node-orm2

I have a simple test or Node ORM and the application runs and creates the record.  But it sits at the command prompt afterwards:

```
var orm = require("orm");

orm.connect('mysql://un-app:unpwd@localhost/dbn', function(err, db) {
     var User  = db.define('user', {
        id              : Number,
        first_name      : String,
        last_name       : String,
        email           : String,
        added_on        : Date,
        active          : Number,
        password        : String,
    }) ; 

    var newUser = {
        first_name: 'Ed'
        , last_name: 'Davis'
        , email: 'ez-eddie@hotmail.com'
        , added_on: new Date().getTime()
        , password: 'test' // encrypt('test')
    }


    User.create(newUser, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user.id)
    });     
})
```

It just sits there:

```
C:\Users\todd\Documents\web\nodeTest\app>node create-user.js
1010
```

I am using windows - so a control-c gets me out of it.  But that cannot be right, can it?  Why is the application waiting there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly you need to close the database connection explicitly to allow the control to fall through:

```
User.create(newUser, function (err, user) {
        //console.log(err)
        console.log(user.id)
        console.log('end of connect')   
        db.close()
    })
```

Can somebody elaborate why?